# jQuery mobile List-View is not working after adding some jquery code

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and I have an array makeArray in jquery and I have created few listview by the values of the array.Everything works fine.But the jquery mobile styled list-view is not shown. Rather it is shown an ordinary list view with no style. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "inventory/inventory.json";
        var makeArray = new Array();
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                if(($.inArray(item.make, makeArray)) == -1){
                    makeArray.push(item.make);
                    $('.upper_case')
                    .append('<li data-icon="list-arrow"> <a href="trade_form.php?='+ item.make +'"><img src="images/car_logo/buick.png" class="ui-li-thumb"/>' + item.make + '</a></li>');
                }
            });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to refresh the listview:

```
  $('upper_case').listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was becoming frustrated with it.Really stack overflow is awesome for some helpful guys like you :)